# Angular 8 and importing Json

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have read a few articles stating you can now import json directly since type script 2.9.
So I have amended my **tsconfig.json** file as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
  "paths": {
    "@data/*": ["src/core/data/*"],
    "@models/*": ["src/core/models/*"],
    "@services/*": ["src/core/*"],
    "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"]
  },
  "resolveJsonModule": true,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
}
```

And then I imported the json into my component like this:

```
import particlesJson from '../../assets/particles.json';
```

It runs fine, but I get an error in the console:

> ERROR in src/app/profile/login.component.ts(3,27): error TS2732: Cannot find module '../../assets/particles.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension

How can I stop that error from appearing?

Comment: What is the typescript version you are using ?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

should be placed under `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`, as per documentation.
See the example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule).

Comment: Does this work for everyone? If it does not work to me,... how can I understand what's the problem? I use Angular 10 and even after restarting "everything" I can't import { version } from '../../../package.json'; I'm getting the same error: Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension.ts(2732)

Comment: @DavideQuaglio strange. I haven't got a repo to try this again tho. Are you sure you're editing the right tsconfig file?

Comment: @LppEdd I think that the problem is that with this approach the file is read only when building the app, and not at runtime right?

Comment: @DavideQuaglio yes. This works at compile time. But this is strictly related to TypeScript. Runtime-speaking it doesn't change anything because we're still working on JavaScript.

Comment: Solves for JSON. However, whereever I import moment like 
"import * as moment from 'moment';" 
compilation fails with "Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead". 

Using require doesn't fix it. @LppEdd please check your answer once

Comment: in angular 8 "resolveJsonModule": true, is enough i think

Answer (score 25):

In my case the good old commputer science approach worked, just restart Visual Studio Code.

Comment: After several hours of debugging, your comment helped me.  Restarting reloads the tsconfig file and helps it work.

Answer (score 1):

Even using LppEdd solution which is the docs. The only solution for me was to add // @ts-ignore The I was able to get json file successfully.

Version: 8

Answer (score 0):

hi in angular 8+ this works if the

```
"resolveJsonModule": true, 
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

is in the tsconfig.add.json and tsconfig.json as well.
I guess VS Code restart is not needed, but some time needs for the vscode to adopt the new ts rules.

Comment: @LppEdd Already did answered it, please, do not poste the same answer again

Answer (score 0):

The problem on my side was that "resolveJsonModule" was not located in "compilerOptions" section