# Cannot find a module json

Tags: json, angular, angular9, tsconfig

I need to import this json file that it is in the `assets` filder.

```
{
    "HOME": "home"
}
```

So I do in my component:

```
  import config from "../../../assets/file/config.json";
```

But I obtain this error:

```
Cannot find module '../../..//config.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension
```

So I modified my `tsconfig.json` in this way:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

But the error it doesn't disappear, it is throwed the same. Anyone can help me?

folder structure is

```
assets/ file/ and in the /file there is the config.jo;
```

Comment: can you provide your folder structure?

Comment: i mean are you sure your relative path is correct?

Comment: @AakashGarg I edit my question /assets/file/config.json. The compile it gives me so If the pat is wroging I read the message "wrong path"

Comment: try my answer below.

Comment: The path is correct!

Comment: try my answer below.

Comment: add * as like i have added below.

Comment: @poopp, Check whether this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57574607/7785337 solves your issue..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan if you read my tsconfig in my question I put these variable  but I think that tsconfig ignore its.

Comment: After modifying `tsconfig`, you need to restart `ng serve`. If it still does not work, you probably have a typo somewhere. Is the error message really `module '../../..//config.json'`, i.e. not mentionning `assets` folder? Did you check the `resolveJsonModule` value in `tsconfig.app.json` in case it's overriden there?

Answer (score 0):

Try the import statement below :-

**import * as config from "../../../assets/file/config.json";**

Comment: stop your server and start again.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing it directly from the asset as :

```
 import config from "assets/file/config.json";
```

And further, if it doesn't work, you may need to set "resolveJsonModule": true in ts.config